# Index for enum collection array doesn't work when querying first record, why is that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, enums, key-value, querying

I have an app with devise users that have the role author or reviewer. I'd like to have a link to go to an index for reviewers or authors. The reviewers index work since it's the second index in the enum roles array.

I named the enum class access_level and in the users controller for the author action I have:

```
def author
    @authors = User.where(["access_level = ?", "0"])
  end
```

However when I click the link in the navigation to go to the authors index I get a list of the reviewrs, which essentially is this below...

```
def reviewer
    @users = User.where(["access_level = ?", "1"])
  end
```

How do I query the authors??

here's my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reviews , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :notifications, foreign_key: :recipient_id

  enum access_level: [:author, :reviewer]

  has_and_belongs_to_many :claims, join_table: :books_users, association_foreign_key: :book_id, class_name: Book.to_s

def full_name
  first_name + " " + last_name
end

end
```

Comment: Are you sure your links are going to the right places? What happens if you `User.where(["access_level = ?", "0"])` (or better `User.where(access_level: :author)`) in the console?

Comment: I fixed it. My controller code was fine. The routes weren't. I defined the routes wrong. Whoops

Comment: You might want to switch to `where(access_level: :author)` and `where(access_level: :reviewer)` anyway (or even the scopes that `enum` automatically adds). Using symbols is a lot more readable than the numbers and passing everything in an array like that is non-idiomatic.